# What does "dafür" in this sentence refer to?

Tags: word-usage, grammar-identification

Could anyone tell me what does *dafür* in this sentence refer to? It's a bit confusing.

> Wenn du kleine Lampe benutzt, sorgst du nachts bei Toilettengängen dafür, dass du nicht das Deckenlicht anmachen musst.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You have to use an article or any other determiner for the subject. An adjective is not a determiner:

> Wenn du **eine** kleine Lampe benutzt, ...

---

Now for your question:

The verb *sorgen* (to take care) can be used in two ways:

1. reflexive, with *"um"*:

   > Gertrud sorgt **sich um** ihre Tochter.
   >   Gertrud worries about her daughter.

   - Gertrud
     subject, a noun
   - sorgt
     predicate, a verb
   - sich
     accusative object, a reflexive pronoun
   - um ihre Tochter
     prepositional object, consisting of a preposition (*um*) and an accusative object (*ihre Tochter*)
2. transitive, with *"für"*

   > Gertrud **sorgt für** ihre Tochter.
   >   Gertrud takes care of her daughter.

   - Gertrud
     subject, a noun
   - sorgt
     predicate, a verb
   - für ihre Tochter
     prepositional object, consisting of a preposition (*für*) and an accusative object (*ihre Tochter*)

So, when the meaning is not *"to worry about something/someone"*, then you have to use a prepositional object that consists of the preposition *"für"* and something else that has to be used in accusative case. Often it is a nominal group (*"ihre Tochter"*), but it also can be a pronoun:

> Gertrud sorgt für **sie.** (Gertrud takes care of **her.**)
>   Gertrud sorgt für **jemanden.** (Gertrud takes care of **someone.**)
>   Gertrud sorgt für **etwas.** (Gertrud takes care of **something.**)

This *"etwas" (something)* in the last example can be a physical thing that you can touch like a house, but it also can be an action, which changes the meaning a little bit.

Until now *"für etwas/jemanden sorgen"* (to take care of something/someone) did mean: To do things, that have a positive effect on the thing or person you take care of.

But when *"etwas"* is an action, *"für etwas/jemanden sorgen"* means to ensure, that this action will happen. But to describe an action, you need a verb, i.e. you have to add another sentence (here, in this case: a subordinate clause that starts with *"dass"*) that describes this action. And this again makes it necessary, that you replace *"etwas"* with something, that refers to this sentence, and this is the word *"da"*, but *"da"* and *"für"* snap together to one word, and this is *"dafür"*:

> Gertrud sorgt **dafür, dass** die Blumen genug Wasser haben.
>   Gertrud makes sure that the flowers have enough water.

---

**Nice to know:**

The pronominal adverb *"dafür"* is not separable in standard German. But in some regions people separate it in colloquial speech. Note, that this is not standard German, but you still might hear it:

> Standard:
>
> - **Dafür** musst du einen Hammer nehmen.
>     *You have to take a hammer for that.*
> - Ich kann nichts **dafür**.
>     *I can't help it.*
> - Ich bin auch **dafür**.
>     *I also agree.*
>
> Colloquial in northern regions:
>
> - **Da** musst du einen Hammer **für** nehmen.
> - **Da** kann ich nichts **für**.
> - **Da** bin ich auch **für**.

Comment: Also nice to know: Southern German custom is to double "da" like 'Da kann ich nichts dafür'

Answer (score 0):

The "dafür" is an adverb and belongs to the verb "sorgen". One english translation for "dafür sorgen" is "to ensure" or "to make sure".

You can find definitions in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/daf%C3%BCr%20sorgen) or in any common dictionary as [Linguee](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/daf%C3%BCr+sorgen.html)